# Is this a case of simultaneous equations?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, linear, instrumental-variables

My model estimates the percentage of living-in agricultural workers (that is, the ones provided with board & accommodation) in labor force. The unit is the % of those workers in a district:

Y = a0 + a1 * cattle + a2 * horses + a3 * popden + a4 * altitude + e

Cattle and horses (more specifically, their densities, i.e. the number divided by acreage) affect demand for labor. Population density is a labor supply factor, and altitude affects both labor supply (via population density) and demand (via animal density).

The results generally make sense, but I am concerned that I combine supply and demand factors in one equation. Is there a way to check if this concern is justified? If it is, what would be the best approach to resolving this issue?

Comment: This is a question to ask of experts in your field, because it's not a statistical question.  You can carry out a regression like this no matter what the variables might represent, so there is no statistical way to determine whether it makes any sense.